# Why can't I pass a json array as data when doing GET request with jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I run a get request like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/points/',
    contentType:"application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({"content_type":content_type,"object_id":object_id}),
    type: 'GET',
  }).error(function(r){ $(output).text('error') })
  .success(function(r){
    $(output).text(r.count);
  })
```

Its request goes to:

> http://localhost:8000/api/points/?{%22content_type%22:8,%22object_id%22:40}

Obviously that's bad. It works okay if I don't do `JSON.stringify()`, but why is that?

Curiously if I do a `POST` request it's the opposite! I have to stringify the data or it won't work. So why the difference?

Comment: for get request, you use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string in url. jQuery will translate a js obj (a hash) into the query string. for post request, you use http body instead of part of url to feed data, that's different story...

Comment: jQuery does a lot of background magic for you, but sometimes you need to understand what's going on behind the scenes.  See my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's fix your request:

```
var req = $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/points/",
    dataType: "json", // is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect. 
    data : {id : '12345'}
});

req.done(function(data){
    // do something with the data
});

req.fail(function(jqXHR, status, err){
    // do something in case of failure
    throw err;
});
```

Next get to know what you are dealing with :

**`data` : PlainObject or String or Array
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.** *By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a **query string**, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".*

Note: *The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.*

At last:

No need for : `JSON.stringify({"content_type":content_type,"object_id":object_id})` as it is a wrong way to do it with `JSON.stringify` just :
`{ 'content_type' : 'type', 'object_id' : 'id' }`

Answer (score 0):

Urahara's answer contains some useful suggestions, but does not seem to address your question.

Well, it seems that your server side code is expecting to find a json object in the body of the POST request.  Why would that be?  Because you specify that the content type be "application/json".  So in the case of a PUT case, when you use JSON.stringify your data in the $.ajax call is a string that happens to represent a JSON object.  This is passed as is and so this works.  You end up sending something like

> {"content_type":8, "object_id":40}

as the body of your POST request and your server side code is happy to process this.  Not sure exactly what your server-side technology is, but presumably it also binds content_type to 8 and object_id to 40, which makes you happy :-)
But when you do not use JSON.stringify to turn the object into a JSON string, you end up passing the object itself to $.ajax having it turn it into a string in the way it knows how.  Well, it only knows only one: the good old url-encoding way.  So the server, would still be expecting a JSON object but would instead be getting

> content_type=8&object_id=40

as the body of the PUT request.  It will not be happy.  This is not a JSON object like your content-type promised! :-)

Now, moving on to the case of a GET request.  Here the content-type is pretty much irrelevant as the message body will be empty. If you use JSON.stringify what you pass as the request data is a weird JSON-object representing string and the monstrosity that you get as a URL

> http://localhost:8000/api/points/?{%22content_type%22:8,%22object_id%22:40}

is as you 'd expect not very well received by the server.   What the server is happy with is something like

> http://localhost:8000/api/points/?content_type=8&object_id=40

Which is exactly what $.ajax produces when you do not use JSON.stringify but rather pass it a nice pair of attribute-value pairs.  It just url-encodes them, exactly like it did in the PUT case, and the server is happy.

So $.ajax always url-encodes objects consisting of attribute-value pairs.  This is fine in most cases.  One way to fix your code to do a POST without using JSON.stringify would be to simply not put a content type parameter in the $.ajax call (in which case the default, 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' will be used).

But if you want to pass more complex, deeply hierarchical objects, using some object serialisation format you have to set the appropriate content type and pass the data as a string using the corresponding encoding (JSON, XML, etc.) like you did here.

Hope that answers your question :-)

Please also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/